# Undefined is not an object at this.state inside singleton

Tags: react-native

I'm fairly new at ReactNative. I have a singleton like this:

```
export default class Locker extends Component {

  static data = Locker.data == null ? new Locker() : this.data;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setState ({ username: "" });
    AsyncStorage.getItem('username', (error, result) => { 
      if (result) { this.setState({ username: result }); } 
    });
    this.getUsername = this.getUsername.bind(this);
    this.setUsername = this.setUsername.bind(this);
  }

  getUsername = () => {
    return this.state.username;
  }

  setUsername = (value) => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('username', value);
    this.setState({ username: value });
  }
}
```

And this is my main app:

```
export default class Home extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.showAlert = this.showAlert.bind(this);
  }

  showAlert() {
    Alert.alert(
      'This is an alert',
      'Your saved username is ' + Locker.data.getUsername(),
      [
        {text: 'OK', onPress: console.log("Done")},
      ],
      {cancelable: false},
    );
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <View style={{ span: 1, backgroundColor: "white" }}>
        <Button title="Press me" onPress={ () => this.showAlert() }/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

When I run the app, I see a button on the screen as expected. When I tap on the button, I get error `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.state.username')`.

Why? I read somewhere that this may be because of `.bind(this)` and arrow function. That's why I add `.bind(this)` and arrow function everywhere. But still not solve the problem. This problem does not arise if I access state on the `Home` main class methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Locker class constructor just replace this code

**from**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setState ({ username: "" });
    AsyncStorage.getItem('username', (error, result) => { 
      if (result) { this.setState({ username: result }); } 
    });
    this.getUsername = this.getUsername.bind(this);
    this.setUsername = this.setUsername.bind(this);
  }
```

**to**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={ username: "" };
    AsyncStorage.getItem('username', (error, result) => { 
      if (result) { this.setState({ username: result }); } 
    });
    this.getUsername = this.getUsername.bind(this);
    this.setUsername = this.setUsername.bind(this);
  }
```

Just need to replace `this.state = { username: "" }`

Answer (score 2):

it is not a good idea to use `setState()`  on the constructor, because react-native will render the component and its children (and this is not a proper thing to do in constructor because the component has not been rendered)
just initiate the state with `this.state = {username: ""};`

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation about why I shouldn't use setState on the constructor. I didn't know that there's a difference between assigning state with an object, and calling setState with an object.

Comment: @ChenLiYong you're welcome.
And also, the initialization this.state={..} is only allowed on the constructor, and should use this.setState(..) everywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

i think it is because of you did not define :

```
this.state = {
    username: ""
}
```

in the constructor method ,replace it just after `super(props)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `this.state = {username: ""}`instead of `this.setState ({username: ""})` in constructor.

You don't need `bind(this)` if you use arrow functions